# Jmeter 2.11 Randomly fails to generate integers

Tags: random, jmeter

I am trying to run some tests, using jmeters random beanshell post processor, but somehow, randomly it fails to create the numbers and instead posts "variable=${variable_value}" directly in the url.

Here is the sample beanshell post processor code:

```
import java.util.*;

r = new Random();
b = new Random();
t = new Random();

random_param1 = r.nextInt(415000);
random_param2 = b.nextInt(200);
random_param3 = t.nextInt(25);

vars.put("random_param1",random_param1.toString());
vars.put("random_param2",random_param2.toString());
vars.put("random_param3",random_param3.toString());
```

And here how I set those for the url:

[image]

And the simple test results looks like this:

[image]

And this is a failed test request data:

```
POST test_url

POST data:
param1=%24%7Brandom_param1%7D&param2=%24%7Brandom_param2%7D&param3=%24%7Brandom_param3%7D
```

While the successful ones are like:

```
POST test_url

POST data:
param1=287341&param2=107&param3=20
```

Any ideas why random generation fails "randomly" like this? Should I use a specific sampler?

EDIT:
[image]
[image]

Comment: show you test plan zooming on beanshell position, thx

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE you mean you wanna see the whole screen with the beanshell?

Comment: By the way, the problem is only happening for the first 20-25 requests, then as the tests are going on, it never repeats

Comment: want to see the whole test, yes thx

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE done, you can check the edit

Comment: check jmeter.log and show complete stacktrace, also how many threads do you set ?

Comment: no errors/exceptions in the logs and thread size doesnt effect the result, i set to 10 and 1000, but still the problem didnt change for the failed random number generation.. i will try to re-run some tests to recreate the problem with finer log levels to see something

Comment: is using beanshell processor mandatory for you?. I think if you need it just for random no. generation you can use random variable. will that do for you?

Comment: @Nachiket well, might work actually, I just need a random no as you said... the point which makes me confused is that the problem does not appear after the first 20 - 25 requests.

Comment: I think that is some kind of code/thread synchronization issue. If you want, I can provide the solution with random no. generator, which I have used and tested many times and I hope you will not face such issue there.let me know if you need it.

Comment: @Nachiket agreed, I am also suspicious about that... I will try to reproduce the problem on vms or other machines, before asking for the random no generator, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Your beanshell code contains an error in the screenshot (so in test plan), you don't set in vars:

- random_param2

Comment: the typo is only on the image, i have fixed it already before running the code, but it didnt help... and still it doesnt explain why param1 and param3 were not set...